# file_get_contents to fetch section of PHP file

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have the following code:

```
<?php 
$path=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$test=file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/test.php?i='.$path);
echo $test;
?>
```

I want to fetch and insert a specific section of the test.php file depending on the $path variable (the url from which the test.php file is accessed.)

How do I do this? Am I on the right track? I don't know how to set up my text.php file so that the function echos the correct section for the webpage it is accessed from. How do I do this? Or is there a better way? (test.php is not a local file)

Thank you!

Comment: let me get this right: you want to grab some PHP code from another site and run it as PHP code within your code? Have you got any idea how much of a security risk that is? In addition, if the code isn't going to change, it's also a massive waste of bandwith to be downloading it across the network every time you load the page. Plus it'll be slow. Very very slow.

Comment: What I want to do is fetch the contents of the PHP file and place a section of it on the site that is accessing it. So the code above will be on many different sites, and the test.php file will be on domain.com. Depending on the URL of the site that is accessing it, I want it to fetch a different section of the test.php file (hence the inclusion of the $path). The contents of the test.php file will periodically change which is why I want to do it this way. Can anyone explain how or if there is a better way? Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear: Accessing it via a URL will run the code on the remote server and send you the output of the program. Do you want that or do you want to download the actual code? It's not totally clear from the question (or from your comment) which of those you want. But if you want to download the code, my advice is don't do it.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. What I want to do is take the plain text of the PHP file and insert into the page where the code above is run. So if www.domain.com/test.php contains <start domain2.com>example text or HTML content<end domain2.com> and th file_get_contents code is on domain2.com/index.php, "example text or HTML content" should be inserted into the source code of index.php.

Comment: I may be approaching this completely wrong, so sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Please, realise that every time you're going to fetch from an outside host your webserver is going to download the file. For a user, this means 2x domain2 + 1x domain1 ~= 3x the amount of loading time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to display dynamic information (such as html or text) on test.php based upon whichever script accesses it. From there, you would like to take the information from test.php and relay it back to index.php by extracting the source code and echoing it? Correct me if I am wrong.

This is achievable using $_GET variables. You were already heading in the right direction by adding the `?i=` to the end of the URL.

Something like this should help you roughly achieve what you want:
(test.php)

```
if (isset($_GET['i]') {
    switch ($_GET['i']) {   
        case 'http://www.domain2.com/index.php':
            echo 'You\'re on domain2.com';
            break; 
        case 'http://www.domain3.com/index.php':
            echo 'You\'re on domain3.com';
            break;
    }
}
```

index.php should work fine how it is, unless the data stored in your variable regarding the path to the page you're currently on is incorrect.

Comment: I actually want to display dynamic information on the domain2.com, domain3.com, etc pages. All of the information will be placed in the test.php file, but it will be selectively fetched to display predefined sections of the file, depending on which site accesses it. So on domain2.com, different information will be fetched and inserted into the source code than the information that is fetched and inserted on domain3.com, etc. How would this be done?

Comment: The solution I posted will achieve what you need. Place it inside test.php. 

In your index.php file, file_get_contents() is saving the html from test.php to a variable and then you are echoing that variable (essentially, you are displaying test.php (which is generated dynamically based on what webpage accesses it) inside of index.php). You are displaying the dynamic information from test.php dynamically on index.php.